# the letter-spacing used in my hover selector on my nav-links is making my logo shift sideways in my navigation bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover, navigationbar

I created a conventional nav-bar using flexbox.
the nav-bar contained 3 divs. Two just had a navlink each while the third contained an image(logo).
the 3 divs are aligned horizontally. the image being in center
I styled the two nav-links with a hover effect that separates the letters when a cursor hovers over it.

```css
*{
 box-sizing:border-box;
}

body{
 background-color:rgb(139, 200, 50);
 
}

nav{
 display:flex;
 justify-content:space-between;
}

#Logo{
 padding:10px;
 margin:0;
 border:0;
 background-color: black;
}

#button{
 align-self:center;
}

#button a {
 text-align: center;
 padding: 10px 30px;
 border: white solid;
 border-radius: 30px;
 cursor: pointer;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-family: 'Heebo', sans-serif;
 color:white;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 transition: 0.8s;
}

#button a:hover{
 color: rgb(139, 200, 50);
 padding: 15px 35px;
 letter-spacing: 3px;
 background-color:#fff;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
 <title>Treetop</title>
</head>
<body>
 <nav >
  <div id="button">
   <a href="">PRODUCTS</a>
  </div>
  <div id="logo">
   <img src="/img/logo.png" alt="logo">
  </div>
  <div id="button">
   <a href="#">CONTACT</a>
  </div>
 </nav>
<body>
```

NOW, the issue is that my image keeps shifting sideways anytime i hover over those nav-links . I do not want the logo to move at all when the nav-links are being hovered. please what should I do? please help.

Answer (score 0):

use `min-width` in button for movement your logo position when hover

```css
*{
 box-sizing:border-box;
}

body{
 background-color:rgb(139, 200, 50);
 
}

nav{
 display:flex;
 justify-content:space-between;
}

#Logo{
 padding:10px;
 margin:0;
 border:0;
 background-color: black;
}

#button{
 align-self:center;
}

#button a {
 text-align: center;
 padding: 10px 30px;
 border: white solid;
 border-radius: 30px;
 cursor: pointer;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-family: 'Heebo', sans-serif;
 color:white;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 transition: 0.8s;
}

#button a:hover{
 color: rgb(139, 200, 50);
 padding: 15px 35px;
 letter-spacing: 3px;
 background-color:#fff;
}

/*Add this**/
div#button {
    min-width: 190px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
 <title>Treetop</title>
</head>
<body>
 <nav >
  <div id="button">
   <a href="">PRODUCTS</a>
  </div>
  <div id="logo">
   <img src="/img/logo.png" alt="logo">
  </div>
  <div id="button">
   <a href="#">CONTACT</a>
  </div>
 </nav>
<body>
```

Comment: nearly perfect. Your right side button is not aligned to the right side anymore.

Answer (score -2):

in your css you have given #Logo instead of

#logo

and give position absolute to #logo wherever you want to position it.